# Getting value of inner object of json

Tags: android, json, android-json

I am a beginner in android coding. I am working on an app which gets data from php web service in JSON format, but I am not able to correctly parse it.

JSON returned looks like this:

```
{
    "posts": [
        {
            "post": {
                "Id": "1",
                "Title": "Captain America",
                "Lang": "ENG"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Android code:

```
JSONObject job = new JSONObject(json);//json is the string returned by web service
jObj = job.getJSONArray("posts");

JSONObject c = jObj.getJSONObject(0);
String title = c.getString("Title");
```

But I get a JSON exception:No value for Title

I cant figure out whats going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have

```
 {  //JSONObject job = new JSONObject(json); ok
    "posts": [  // jObj = job.getJSONArray("posts"); ok
        {        // JSONObject c = jObj.getJSONObject(0) ok 
            "post": { // forgot about jsonobject post // missed  JSONObject post = c.getJSONObject("post")
                "Id": "1",
                "Title": "Captain America",
```

Change to

```
 JSONObject c = jObj.getJSONObject(0);
 JSONObject post = c.getJSONObject("post");
 String title = post.getString("Title");
```

Comment: Oh, I cant believe I got stuck there for over an hour. Thanks very much for the explanation @Raghunandan. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject job = new JSONObject(json);//json is the string returned by web service
JSONArray jar=job.getJSONArray("posts");
    for (int i=0;i<jar.length();i++)
    {
        job=jar.getJSONObject(i);
        job=jat.getJSONObject("post");
        title=job.optString("Title");
    }
```

You forget to get "post" value